# Lottie files not loading inside lazy column in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-animation, android-jetpack-compose, lottie

I tried to load Lottie animation inside `LazyColumn` by importing as `json` but animation dint loaded.The same I tried inside `Column` it worked well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LottieAnimation` uses `Modifier.fillMaxSize()` inside, and this modifier doesn't work correctly inside scrollable views.

From `Modifier.fillMaxSize()` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).fillMaxSize(kotlin.Float)):

> If the incoming maximum width or height is `Constraints.Infinity` this modifier will have no effect in that dimension.

The `LazyColumn` has vertical scrolling inside, and this makes the height constraint equal to `Constraints.Infinity` to allow you to add as many elements as you need.

You can fix this by setting a constant height with `Modifier.height`, or a size-dependent `LazyColumn` with [`Modifier.fillParentMaxHeight()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyItemScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).fillParentMaxHeight(kotlin.Float))

```
LazyColumn {
    item {
        LottieAnimation(
            composition = ..., 
            progress = ...,
            modifier = Modifier.fillParentMaxHeight(0.5f)
        )
    }
}
```